# web app on top of a REST API - how to persist data between page requests?

Tags: json, ajax, rest

I'm starting with web development these days and I would prefer so called client side rendering. In practice that ajax request needed data and add them to the html file ( which has already the static content, and dynamic data is added via 2nd request ). I like this approach, cause of a clean seperation between client and server. You just need to define an API and you can seperate the work.
So if you don't create the dynamic content on server side, how dou you persist data between page requests.
For example, you are on a overview for a list of adresses. You can click a button to edit a specific adress with id "25". That will requiere a new html file for that task, which will be loaded and rendered. How does the javascript included in that html file know, which adress should be loaded. How can it access the id "25"?

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1. You don't persist anything on the client and simply reload everything as you go back and forth between the list page and the editor page. Editor page gets the id "25" and loads corresponding item either using AJAX, as you want, or on the server.

Approach 2. You do everything on the same page (SPA). You use JavaScript and probably some framework like Angular to maintain your page state.